# Application Insights query to get time between 2 custom events

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am trying to write a query that will get me the average time between 2 custom events, sorted by user session. I have added custom tracking events throughout this application and I want to query the time it takes the user from 'Setup' event to 'Process' event.

```
let allEvents=customEvents
| where timestamp between (datetime(2019-09-25T15:57:18.327Z)..datetime(2019-09-25T16:57:18.327Z))
| extend SourceType = 5;
let allPageViews=pageViews
| take 0;
let all = allEvents
| union allPageViews;
let step1 = materialize(all
| where name == "Setup" and SourceType == 5
| summarize arg_min(timestamp, *) by user_Id
| project user_Id, step1_time = timestamp);
let step2 = materialize(step1
| join
    hint.strategy=broadcast                      (all
    | where name == "Process" and SourceType == 5
    | project user_Id, step2_time=timestamp
)
on user_Id
| where step1_time < step2_time
| summarize arg_min(step2_time, *) by user_Id
| project user_Id, step1_time,step2_time);
let 1Id=step1_time;
let 2Id=step2_time;
1Id
| union 2Id
| summarize AverageTimeBetween=avg(step2_time - step1_time)
| project AverageTimeBetween
```

When I run this query it produces this error message:

'' operator: Failed to resolve table or column or scalar expression named 'step1_time'

I am relatively new to writing queries with AI and have not found many resources to assist with this problem. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `let 1id=step1_time` lines are intended to do.

those lines are trying to declare a new value, but step1_time isn't a thing, it was a *field* in another query

i'm also not sure why you're doing that `pageviews | take 0` and unioning it with events?

```
let allEvents=customEvents
| where timestamp between (datetime(2019-09-25T15:57:18.327Z)..datetime(2019-09-25T16:57:18.327Z))
| extend SourceType = 5;
let step1 = materialize(allEvents
| where name == "Setup" and SourceType == 5
| summarize arg_min(timestamp, *) by user_Id
| project user_Id, step1_time = timestamp);
let step2 = materialize(step1
| join
    hint.strategy=broadcast (allEvents
    | where name == "Process" and SourceType == 5
    | project user_Id, step2_time=timestamp
)
on user_Id
| where step1_time < step2_time
| summarize arg_min(step2_time, *) by user_Id
| project user_Id, step1_time,step2_time);
step2
| summarize AverageTimeBetween=avg(step2_time - step1_time)
| project AverageTimeBetween
```

if I remove the things I don't understand (like union with 0 pageviews, and the lets, I get a result, but I don't have your data so I had to use other values than "Setup" and "Process" so I don't know if it is what you expect?

you might want to look at the results of the `step2` query without the summarize to just see what you're getting matches what you expect.